# Can anybody help me in obfuscating with android procredures?

Tags: android, obfuscation

I was struggling for past one week to do obfuscate with android application can any one help me in step by step process to get it done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are building within Eclipse?

- In the root directory of project, there is a file called default.properties and a file called proguard.cfg.
- Add the property "proguard.config=proguard.cfg" to your default.properties.
- Build your project with right-click/AndroidTools/ExportSignedApplicationPackage

Comment: Hello Marc, yes your assumption is correct i am trying to do it with eclipse. As you said, i cant able to fine any file called default properties in my application. I could able to find only project.properties. Can add the line "proguard.config=proguard.cfg" in project.properties file and how to check the obfuscation is done after that. Please help me.

Comment: If obfuscation is successful, a proguard subdirectory is also created in your project containing the mappings.  One easy way to double-check that obfuscation is working is by adding a line like Thread.dumpStack() somewhere in your code.  The resulting loglines should show the obfuscated functions-names.

Comment: Hi Marc, Obfuscation was successful.Thanks for your help. Yes proguard subdirectory was created but the subdirectory was empty. What should actually have inside that folder. How can i check after adding Thread.dumpStack() in my code.

Comment: the proguard directory should have (among others) a mapping.txt file containing the original function (and variable) names and the function names after obfuscation.  Is this file present (and is the last modified date what you expect)?  I also have a dump.txt, seeds.txt and usage.txt file in this directory but never used those.

Comment: Hi Marc, Idont have any of the files inside the subdirectory proguard. I dont know where i made mistake

Comment: Which Android version are you targetting? >= 14? That would at least explain why you see project.properties instead of default.properties. See http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14 If you run Android Tools/ExportSignedApplicationPackage, do you see a resulting  apk file?

Comment: Hi Marc,I am using android version 2.2 and minSdkVersion = 7 and maxSdkVersion = 10.  I got .apk file finally but i dont find any file inside the proguard subdirectory thats y i am confused.

Comment: Can you press F5 on your project in Eclipse and see whether the "default.properties" file appears?

Comment: Hi Marc, Really I am sorry. Now i got all the files in proguard folder after i clean and refresh my code thank you so much for your help.